# How can I change the name of an application as it appears to pgrep?

Tags: macos, sh

How can I change the name of a running macOS process, such that running `pgrep -x oldApplicationName` will not return anything, but running `pgrep -x newApplicationName` will return the processes id, the same one `pgrep -x oldApplicationName` would have returned before changing the name?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why would you think this is possible? Are you using the native macOS `pgrep`, or a GNU `pgrep`?

Comment: I am using the native macOS pgrep.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the name of a running process, though you can *choose* a name (for example, using `exec -a` in `bash`) when the process is started.

Comment: I don't know where the source code for macOS's native `pgrep` can be found (it might even be closed source), but I assume it gets its information from the macOS's kernel. The kernel will be keeping track of the name of each process (technically speaking, the `comm`) in its own internal data structures. So I don't think it is possible (in user space) to change what `pgrep` returns. Alternatively, I suppose you could write your own `pgrep` implementation to do whatever you want it to.